# Angular JS and JQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, error-handling, datepicker, required

My birthdate field was created by JQuery using datepicker function then the required field validation is handled by AngularJS using ng-show whenver I submit the form there is a error handling but when I choose date in the field the error message is not remove.

```
<input type="text name="birthdate" id="datepicker" ng-model="birthdate" readonly required >
  <span id="errordate" ng-show="submitted && form.birthdate.$error.required">*required</span><br>

<script>
          $function(){
           $('#datepicker').datepicker();
         });
</script>
```

[Here is the form look at the birthdate field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x5t1.png)
 Please Help me thank you.

Comment: Is there any question?

Comment: my question sir is the error message in birthdate field is not removing when I select a date.

Comment: Please take a look on my answer. I included an snippet code for ui bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery and angular are [paradigmatically](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/27/using-angularjs-stop-using-jquery-as-a-crutch/) differents.

If you want a jQuery like query selector. Please use the [built in jQuery](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) from angular.

For date picker you should use [Ui-bootstrap.](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) It's 100% angular compatible. You won't see those errors.

> Take a look in this snippet with ui-bootstrap [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/zg74L75o/)

In case you **need** to  use **jQuery**. Every moment you chance any attribute that angular are "watching"  you have to update the angular's digest with:

```
$scope.$apply()
```

Where all `$scope` attributes will update the values.

> However, I strongly suggest you to don't use `$apply()` never. I
>   suggest you to **not use jQuery** as well.

Comment: Thank you now I understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery DatePicker apply change to `<input>`, AngularJS does not know this change, you must call `$scope.$apply()` to make AngularJS check and apply new changes. But I think you should use `$timeout` to apply this change and avoid AngularJS inprog error, more information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog).

Here is my [ONLINE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jer0d084/). Hope this help!